# Cgi downloads instead executing when opening in browser/ localhost

Tags: apache, cgi, apache2.4, osx-yosemite-beta

I upgraded to OS X 10.10, and by inherence to Apache 2.4. I have a .cgi app that i try to run but downloads when I try to open it on any browser.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

CGI apps are often written in Perl.

For Yosemite, Apple upgraded the installed version of Apache to 2.4 and shipped it without mod_perl. In past versions of OS X, you could open

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

and uncomment the following line:

```
#LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
```

then restart apache:

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

however, the **"LoadModule"** line is no longer there, and mod_perl is no longer at libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so.

**Since the programming language is missing for your CGI app, the browser just prints out the code instead of executing it.**

You have to install mod_perl if you want your script to be executed. There are various sites that try to explain how to do it but it is complex and Yosemite is recent. I have not yet found a site that provides working instructions.

Comment: "CGI apps are written in Perl." No. CGI is an interface. Applications conforming to it can be written in any language - C, shell scripts, Java, Python, etc.